# Websphere and logback

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, websphere, java-ee-6, logback

I created a dynamic web project using IBM Rational Application Developer (RAD). I used Logback as the logging framework. I put the logback.xml in WEB-INF/classes. But the application does not pickup this configuration file. Logging inflormation are logged in console. But I expect this to logged in a file. Please see the logback.xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>myApp.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>myApp.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
            <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
            <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>2MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>

    </appender>

    <logger name="com.nyl.ltc.logging.handler" level="ALL" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I put the following jars in WEB-INF/lib

1. logback-classic-1.0.11.jar
2. logback-core-1.0.11.jar
3. slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar

I am using WebSphere Application Server v7.0.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Note: I run the application in RAD's internal browser.

Comment: Can you post your classpath?

Comment: @Terrell Plotzki: I am not sure what do you expect. I put logback.xml in WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Just trying to help, if you are running from within Eclipse your code may be in another directory. Are you seeing this line in the console?
`|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml]`

Comment: No. When I did the same application in ecipse(Server: Tomcat) I can see that line.

Comment: Do you get solution? I found same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a jvm system property in websphere:

logback.configurationFile=/tmp/logback.xml

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use ServletContextListener and set logback to context.

### web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>logbackLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.listener.LogbackListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

### LogbackListener

```
package com.listener;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.servlet.*;
import org.slf4j.*
import ch.qos.logback.*;

public class LogbackListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "logbackLocation";

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        String location = servletContext.getInitParameter(CONFIG_LOCATION);
        // check location

        InputStream inputStream = openInputStream(servletContext, location);
        // check inputStream
        try {
            configureLogback(/*params*/);
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 servletContext.log("Could not close logback config inputstream.", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private InputStream openInputStream(ServletContext servletContext, String location) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        if (location == null)
            return inputStream;
        if (location.startsWith("/"))
            inputStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream(location);
        else
            try {
                inputStream = new URL(location).openStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            //ommited
            }
        if (inputStream == null)
            try {
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(location);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //ommited
            }
        return inputStream;
    }

    private void configureLogback(/*params*/) {
        //implementation ommited
    }

     public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        loggerContext.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anton. But I dont understand the purpose of having this ContextListener. Currently the issue is in Websphere environment couldnt load the logback.xml at runtime. Can you please explain how your answer help me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add a shared lib into Websphere admin console, to your logback.xml